# Default printer is not returned in windows 10

Tags: java, printing, java-8, windows-10

I have updated my windows environment from 8 to 10 and found that the default printer is not being returned and a different one is returned instead.

I have turned off the "Let windows manage my default printer" setting, but still not getting the default printer.

I have the following code:

```
 private void testPrinter() {
    PrintService[] array = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, null);
    for(PrintService ps : array){
        System.out.println(ps.getName());
    }

}
```

In this test, I get a list of printers as following:

- Send to one note
- Microsoft XPS Document Writer
- HP printer
- Epson Printer (which is set as my default printer in windows)

However, in the following test:

```
 PrintService ps = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
 System.out.println(ps.getName());
```

I get the HP printer, which is not my default printer!!! No matter which printer I chose as a default, the HP printer is returned always

I went through the java API for lookupDefaultPrintService method and it says the following:

> Locates the default print service for this environment. This may
>   return null. If multiple lookup services each specify a default, the
>   chosen service is not precisely defined, but a platform native
>   service, rather than an installed service, is usually returned as the
>   default. If there is no clearly identifiable platform native default
>   print service, the default is the first to be located in an
>   implementation-dependent manner.
>
> This may include making use of any preferences API that is available
>   as part of the Java or native platform. This algorithm may be
>   overridden by a user setting the property javax.print.defaultPrinter.
>   A service specified must be discovered to be valid and currently
>   available to be returned as the default.

In windows 8, there was no issue with returning the default printer. After updating I'm getting this problem. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in this [guide](https://www.thurrott.com/windows/windows-10/62508/windows-10-tip-disable-automatic-default-printer-management), Windows 10 reconfigure your default printer each time you print, setting the default as the last used device. You have to change this setting.

Edit: You can also try to directly disable the feature via registry (regedit.exe), searching for all `LegacyDefaultPrinterMode DWORD` instances and setting them to 1 (off). Usually the main instance is here:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows
```

Comment: I have turned off the "Let windows manage my default printer" feature , but even with that I'm still not being able to get the default printer! As explained in the question.

Comment: @fareed I've edited my answer with a more radical solution.

Comment: @Matteo Baldi, maybe you can help on the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36686367/let-windows-manage-my-default-printer-is-missing 

Thanks