# "Let Windows manage my default printer" is missing

Tags: printing, operating-system, registry, windows-10, printers

**Update:**

Based on down votes I got, I decided to explain why I am asking this question.
I am writing a C# application that use the default printer.

The problem is when printing in Windows 10 through my application, the default printer is not returned as expected.

After some research, I found that it is a new feature developed by Microsoft: the last printer used for print is being the default one. However, that it is possible to turn this feature off.

**Now, back to the original post:**

I have Windows 10 installed and I am trying to turn off the "Let Windows manage my default printer" but I cannot find this option.

[image]

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35958538/default-printer-is-not-returned-in-windows-10/36471189#36471189) answer, I tried to turn it off through regedit but the instance of LegacyDefaultPrinterMode is also not there.

Any idea why I cannot find turn off option?
Is there any other alternative to turn this flag off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How to disable automatic default printer manager**

1- Use the Windows Key + I keyboard shortcut to open Settings.

2- Navigate to Devices, then go to Printers & scanners, and disable the Let Windows manage my default printer.

[image]

Comment: using shortcut to open the Devices is not helping to make the flag visible. Thanks

Comment: http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/26138-printer-turn-off-let-windows-10-manage-default-printer.html This should help.

Comment: This tutorial helped me understand that I do not have the build containing this option installed. I need to build 10565. Thanks